# SQL query summary issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I'm new to SQL and trying to create a total summary of a working SQL query. It's listing the total results from one month of data.
Now I need the total values of the outcome of the query.
So I created a 'query in a query' piece of SQL, but it ain't working because my lack of SQL knowledge. I guess it's an easy fix for you pro's :-)

The working SQL query with the daily outcome of one month:

```
SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%y') AS Datum,
          COUNT(*) AS Berichten,
          SUM(CASE WHEN virusinfected>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Virus,
          SUM(CASE WHEN (virusinfected=0 OR virusinfected IS NULL) AND isspam>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ongewenst,
          SUM(CASE WHEN (virusinfected=0 OR virusinfected IS NULL) AND (isspam=1) AND isrblspam>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RBL,
          SUM(size) AS Grootte
         FROM
          maillog
         WHERE
          1=1
        AND (1=1)
        AND
         date < '2017-04-01'
        AND
         date >= '2017-03-01'
        AND
         to_domain = 'domain1.nl'
        OR
        date < '2017-04-01'
        AND
         date >= '2017-03-01'
        AND
         to_domain = 'domain2.nl'

         GROUP BY
          Datum
         ORDER BY
          date
```

The incorrect query trying to create the monthly totals:

```
SELECT  Datum,
    SUM(Berichten) AS Berichten,
    SUM(Virus) AS Virus,
    SUM(Ongewenst) AS Ongewenst,
    SUM(RBL) AS RBL,
    SUM(Grootte) AS Grootte,
    FROM    (   SELECT
                  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%y') AS Datum,
                  COUNT(*) AS Berichten,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN virusinfected>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Virus,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN (virusinfected=0 OR virusinfected IS NULL) AND isspam>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ongewenst,
                  SUM(CASE WHEN (virusinfected=0 OR virusinfected IS NULL) AND (isspam=1) AND isrblspam>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RBL,
                  SUM(size) AS Grootte
                 FROM
                  maillog
                 WHERE
                  1=1
                AND (1=1)
                AND
                 date < '2017-04-01'
                AND
                 date >= '2017-03-01'
                AND
                 to_domain = 'domain1.nl'
                OR
                date < '2017-04-01'
                AND
                 date >= '2017-03-01'
                AND
                 to_domain = 'domain2.nl'

                 GROUP BY
                  Datum
                 ORDER BY
                  date
            ) t
    GROUP BY Datum;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want can be done with just a little addition to your first SQL statement: add [`with rollup`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) after the `group by` clause:

```
GROUP BY Datum WITH ROLLUP
```

It will run more efficiently than the version with sub-query, although it could work that way, but you should then remove the outer `group by` clause and not select `Datum` there, since you *don't* want the totals per date any more, but overall.

Still, you will lose the details and only get the overall totals then. You would have to use a union with your original query to get both levels of totals. You can imagine that the `with rollup` modifier will do the job more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks a lot trincot!

Comment: Graag gedaan ;-)